# Does a spear fighter suffer the Power Attack penalty on parries and ripostes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

A fighter that takes the archetype [spear fighter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/spear-fighter-fighter-archetype/) uses the feats [Power Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat/), [Furious Focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/furious-focus-combat/), and [Improved Furious Focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/flaming-crab-games/general-feats-3rd-party-flaming-crab-games/improved-furious-focus/). If he uses parry and riposte, does he incur the penalties from having used Power Attack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, the *Power Attack* penalty to attack rolls is applied when using the *Spear Fighter’s Spear Parry* ability.

This is because the parry is an attack of opportunity - *as outlined in the quotes below* - which does not benefit from *Improved Furious Focus*, as the feat explicitly calls them out as not affected.

> **Spear Parry:**
>   At 3rd level, a spear fighter learns to parry his opponents’ attacks with his spear. *This functions as a swashbuckler’s opportune parry and riposte deed*....
>
> **Opportune Parry and Riposte:**
>   ...when an opponent makes a melee attack against the swashbuckler, she can spend 1 panache point and expend a use of an attack of opportunity to attempt to parry that attack. *The swashbuckler makes an attack roll as if she were making an attack of opportunity*....
>
> **Improved Furious Focus:**
>   When you are wielding a two-handed weapon or a one-handed weapon in two hands and using the Power Attack feat, you do not suffer Power Attack’s penalty on attack rolls on your turn. *You still suffer the penalty on attacks of opportunity.*

*(Keep in mind you also still have the penalty when taking attacks of opportunity during your own turn)*

Comment: So, if the parry and riposte is an AOO, do you think it benefits from Deceitful Incompetence and the half elf racial Eye for Opportunity?

Comment: Absolutely it does, yes.